# Kill docker-compose containers without docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have some docker containers provisioned by docker-compose with `restart: always` flag. But I accidentally delete docker-compose.yml file.

How do I delete those containers so that they will not restart automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without the compose file, docker-compose can't guess the name of the containers that need to be killed. You need to do that manually using docker command:

```
docker container ls
docker rm -f <container-name-or-id>
```

Comment: Won't these containers restart due to restart:always?

Comment: @yamenk thankyou. Turned out the containers will not restart if delete directly by docker command

Answer (score 3):

You can use `docker ps -a` to list all the running containers. After you can use `docker stop container-name` to stop individually the containers you want and after you can use `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` to delete and remove all the stopped containers.

Also if you want to delete the docker images as well you can use `docker images` to list the existing images and after `docker rmi image-name` to delete the image.

Comment: thank you, your solution is radical but rather good for development

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue - I didn't *want* to fetch the .yml files just to remove the containers. As docker-compose adds labels to the containers, we can use these to filter the matching containers and then remove them.

To remove all the containers that docker-compose created for project ProjectName (normally the name of the folder where the `docker-compose.yml` was) in shell (bash or similar), execute the following:

```
docker ps --filter 'label=com.docker.compose.project=ProjectName' --format {{.ID}} | xargs -n 1 docker rm --force --volumes
```

`docker ps` with the filter provides the list of containers, the format is provided so that only container IDs are printed
`xargs -n 1` - takes the list of container IDs and executes the target command on each of them providing the container ID as the argument to the target
`docker rm` removes existing containers
`--force` - to also stop running containers (otherwise running containers would not be stopped or removed)
`--volumes` - to also remove any anonymous volumes associated with the containers

Comment: Thanks for this! It was exactly what I was looking for :)
Just a small comment: There is a typo in the command. It says `xarg` and it should be `xargs`.